# regex not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

IE version 8

The regex is working fine in firefox:

filename variable contains: testfile.arv (see invalid extension)

```
if (/\.(doc|xls|ppt|eml|txt|pdf|rtf).?\b/i.test(filename)) {
...
}
```

in IE it simply passes out as valid name.

EDIT:
After I changed the expression as suggested below. it continued to fail - in IE only. made me realize that it is not about this expression but something about IE and the javascript module I am using to do this.

I am using http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ this form plugin to upload multiple files. this is working properly on firefox, but is not working on internet explorer. it just simply uploads everything and does not show upload progress etc.

since this problem is turning out to be different I will close this thread and submit new question.

Thx for everyone's time and sorry for trouble. I am finding this porting thing a little difficult (from firefox to IE)

Comment: I will consider giving you advice, when you consider taking the time to write words out in full.

Comment: are you downgrading this? and can you 'explain' your comment above  'in full'.

Comment: It is pretty self-explanatory. "pl." and "ty." are not English words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ending it with an "$", like so

```
if (/\.(doc|xls|ppt|eml|txt|pdf|rtf)$/i.test(filename)) {
  // super awesome code
}
```

Comment: thx i tried this but it seems my problem is with malsup jquery form plugin and IE.